# Does set_error_handler() work on most cheap virtual webspace hosting accounts?

Tags: php

I'd like to use set_error_handler() to handle all PHP errors in one place, but I'm afraid that this is something I can't use with cheap webspace hosters. Or must I not worry much about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_error_handler` is just a normal function of PHP -- so it should work on any hosting service.

I really don't see any reason that would justify for a hosting service to disable that function -- and I've never seen it disabled.

Answer (score 2):

PHP allows to disable functions with the [`disable_functions` directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions). But I don’t see any reason for why anyone would not allow `set_error_handler`.

Comment: Interesting.  I've never encountered that before, but then again, I usually build my own servers, so I guess it's something I don't really need.

Answer (score 1):

`set_error_handler()` is part of the core PHP error handling functions, so it should work on any host.

There isn't a way to disable it that I know of, although setting the [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) level to 0 would make it so the handler was never called.  This is something you have complete control over however.

Comment: I suppose it could be disabled with the disable_functions (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions ) directive ; but I don't see why it would be disabled...

Comment: @Pascal - I just commented on Gumbo's answer about that, very interesting directive!  I've never seen it used before.

Comment: I've seen it used for functions such as popen and fsockopen (The hosting company we use at work disables those, and a couple of others,  by default)